# Can I use OrmLite in a commercial project?

Tags: java, licensing, ormlite

[OrmLite](http://ormlite.com/) is licensed under the [Creative Commons 3.0 license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/).  Can I use the library in a commercial project, which I sell to customers, without providing my own source code to the customer?

**Important editation of the question:**
I found now, that just the website is licensed under the CC license!
[The software it self appears to be free. But I did not find yet, which name the license has.](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/doc-files/ormlite_9.html#License)

Which requirements must I fullfil to be allowed to do so?

Comment: I do not understand this requirement: "ShareAlike — If you remix, transform, or build upon the material, you must distribute your contributions under the same license as the original."

Does it mean, that if I link against the library, I must publish my code under the CC license too?

Comment: 1) it says "for any purpose, even commercially." - commercial use is rarely ever a problem with open source licenses. Except for the CC "NC" (non-commercial) ones. 2) "share alike" is more difficult. http://mollykleinman.com/2008/08/29/cc-howto-share-alike/ - I don't know if one needs to consider including that library a "derivative work". Edit: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORMLite says "ISC" license

Comment: because it is not licensed under the CC it should be no problem to use it. Let's leave the question like it is for other people stumbeling upon the same question

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing, not programming or software development. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORMLite code is not licensed under CC 3.0, it is released under the [ISC license](https://opensource.org/licenses/ISC).  To quote from the [license section of the manual](http://ormlite.com/docs/license):

> Permission to use, copy, modify, and/or distribute this software for any purpose with or without fee is hereby granted, provided that this permission notice appear in all copies.
>
> THE SOFTWARE IS PROVIDED "AS IS" AND THE AUTHOR DISCLAIMS ALL WARRANTIES WITH REGARD TO THIS SOFTWARE INCLUDING ALL IMPLIED WARRANTIES OF MERCHANTABILITY AND FITNESS. IN NO EVENT SHALL THE AUTHOR BE LIABLE FOR ANY SPECIAL, DIRECT, INDIRECT, OR CONSEQUENTIAL DAMAGES OR ANY DAMAGES WHATSOEVER RESULTING FROM LOSS OF USE, DATA OR PROFITS, WHETHER IN AN ACTION OF CONTRACT, NEGLIGENCE OR OTHER TORTIOUS ACTION, ARISING OUT OF OR IN CONNECTION WITH THE USE OR PERFORMANCE OF THIS SOFTWARE.

I think you are getting confused by the license at the bottom of the *web-pages* which is CC-3.0.

Comment: What does ISC stand for?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your software

Comment: Added link to the ISC license @tokam.  https://opensource.org/licenses/ISC